# Web sites help and advice

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, redirect, parameters, html

I have a little cellphone gadget/device which does a report home(call home) whenever a button is pressed.
The device calls home to URL "www.abc.com/intakes/register_intakes?msisdn=0841234567" and reports its Cell number (or msisdn). 
The Cell number and the date/time should be then stored in a mysql database and thus the server application will which user has reported and at what time. The only thing that can be configured in the device (via a text file) is www.abc.com.

The URL must be EXACTLY as listed above (except for the number of course), as I dont have the source code for the device.

My knowledge of html and websites is very weak and thus I'm seeking this help.

I want to know how to write a small web app to receive the msisdn number in the URL and then to write this number into a database. The hurdle is that is must match the url above.

Is there anyone that knows how to achieve this?

Many Thanks

Following on from Alex's advice, I have managed to overcome the problem I raised above.
Hopefully, this could help someone else.

1. I used the uniform server as my WAMP server. (No Need to install anything just unzip and run, much easier)
2. Apended the following on the .htaccess file found in the www directory.

   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule ^/?intakes/register_intakes$ intakes/register_intakes.php [L]
3. In file register_intakes.php I had the following:

   ```
   $param = $_GET['msisdn'];

   $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dialup (msisdn) VALUES(" . $param . ") ");
   if (!$result) { 
       die(mysql_error());  
   }
   echo $param . " Inserted into Dialup database";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "No Number received!"; 
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: [google.com](http://www.google.com) is a good place to start with...

Comment: Why are you in such a hurry to close this down. At least give some people a chance to point a person in some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many possible solutions:
Assuming that you work with LAMP or WAMP, you have to

- configure Apache's mod_rewrite so that your URL points to a PHP
  script on your server (e.g. myscript.php);
- evaluate the GET parameter "msisdn" in that script and
- store it via the mysqli API in your database.

Since scripting this task is a matter of minutes rather than of days I recommend that you seek professional help if you don't want to climb a steep learning curve only for this task.